# XSLT why sort function doesn't work with more specific path?

Tags: xml, xslt

I met a problem when I try to transform my xml file to another one. It needs to sorted with the city name.But my sort function doesn't work!!

this is my cities.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cities.xsl"?>
<cities>
<city id="c01">
    <name>Shanghai</name>
    <population>1111000</population>
    <altitude>450</altitude>
</city>

<city id="c02">
    <name>Wenzhou</name>
    <population>277200</population>
    <altitude>220</altitude>
</city>

<city id="c03">
    <name>Beijing</name>
    <population>2222000</population>
    <altitude>662</altitude>
</city>
</cities>
```

This is the cities.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="cities">
    <cities>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="city/name"/>  //doesn't work!!!
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </cities>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="city">
    <city>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </xsl:attribute> 
        <inhabitants>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="population"/>
        </inhabitants>
    </city>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="population">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I change the line with

```
<xsl:sort select="name"/>  //it works!!!
```

Who can tell me why ??Please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the expression `city/name` by which you are trying to sort the `city` elements, is evaluated from the context of `city` - and from that context it returns nothing, because `city` is not a child of itself.

See:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#sorting

---

### Added:

> what's the difference between this example from mine?

**In the given example (simplified):**

```
<xsl:template match="employees">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
      <xsl:sort select="name/family"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

- Initial context: `employees`
- Nodes to be processed: `employee`
- Sort by expression: `name/family`

The combined path to the sort key value: `employees/employee/name/family`

**In your example (slightly adjusted for clarity):**

```
<xsl:template match="cities">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="city">
      <xsl:sort select="city/name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

- Initial context: `cities`
- Nodes to be processed: `city`
- Sort by expression: `city/name`

The combined path to the sort key value: `cities/city/city/name`

Do you see the problem with this path?

Comment: I have seen that link but i am still confused,                                       <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
      <xsl:sort select="name/family"/>  what's the difference between this example from mine? Thank you.

Comment: @Grumpy.jenny I have added a comparison to my answer.